# Mosh and ssh stopped working after connection through VPN channel

Tags: ssh, vpn, remote-access

I've had absolutely no problem since I started accessing the remote university server via VPN last month, but today something went wrong and I can't fix it on my own.

Here's what I usually do:

I use Forticlient VPN to connect to the uni network. Then I mosh/ssh to the computational server: mosh username@host, and it worked until today. Ther error message I'm getting now is

> ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
>
> /usr/bin/mosh: Did not find remote IP address (is SSH ProxyCommand
>   disabled?).

In /etc/ssh/ssh_config I uncommented the line with the ProxyCommand:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
```

where `-W %h:%p` refers to username@hostname, but it didn't help, same error. I tried pinging the server, it returns Destination Host Unreachable error message.

Any suggestions? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably you're doing nothing wrong but the server is down.

Comment: Yeah maybe, but there's no way I could verify that in the next 12 hours